# Android some asset files/directories not being included in apk

Tags: android, assets

It appears directories named private and files names that start with __ are not being included or are not being seen by the assetManager.list(path) .  Is this an Android rule?  Is this something specific to how eclipse behaves?  Or??  Is there a way around this?  I really, don't want to rename things.

For example:

```
assets->dir1->private->*

assets->dir2->__test__.txt
```

private won't be there
`__test__.txt` won't be there.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your directory structure?

Comment: updated question, exact directory structure is complex.  this should be sufficient.

Comment: Is there something specific about your files that are being omitted? Like they are of larger size?

Comment: Examine your APK and see if they are in there. APKs are just ZIP files, and your assets should be directly visible. Regardless, I suspect that you will wind up renaming things.

Comment: they are not larger size.  their names are what is interesting about them.

Comment: They are not being included in the APK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a filename starts with _ it will not be part of the APK.  If a directory only contains files that start with _ or no files, it will not be part of the APK.  I am sure there are more rules, but I didn't see them defined anywhere.